# How can I repair a carpeted floor partly worn down by an office chair?

Tags: carpet

I'm a tad worried over the current state of the carpeted flooring in my room. Over the past two to three years I'd used an office chair (on casters) without a floor mat in said room and the spot where it was used left a kind of dent that has only grown bigger since I replaced the chair with a folding camping seat.

Will I be required to replace the floorboards underneath the carpet? I can't tear up the carpeting and give further details so I can only assume that the floorboards underneath buckled as indicated by the slightly expansive warping and the noticeably uneven at times creaking boards underfoot.

Thanks in advance.

edit: this floor is located on the first story of the house. To my knowledge, there is a crawlspace underneath.

edit 2: I consulted the homeowner about the floor and she'd said that the subfloor was composed of plywood boards that are at least three to four inches thick.

Comment: Has the carpet worn through completely?  Can you post a pic or two?

Comment: We won't be able to tell you much without knowing what type of subfloor you have and whether it's actually damaged.

Comment: If you're asking if the carpet has been worn until the floorboards show through, then no. However the wear is clearly noticeable as closer inspection reveals a much lighter colouration as well as an inch's worth of downwards buckling/drooping. If I can I shall attach a picture later.

Comment: If your chair damaged the floor under the carpet you have much bigger problems with the structure of the home. I agree with @Fred shope. +

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you tried to edit without logging into your user account, so the edit shows up in a review queue as proposed by an anonymous user.  BTW, it's doubtful that the subfloor is composed of plywood boards that are at least three to four inches thick.

Answer (score 4):

Possible, but unlikely.

It's not unusual for chairs used like this to create a ring of matted carpet where you usually sit, and the frequent pressure can damage the carpet's pad as well, giving the illusion of deep indentation. This is more pronounced with certain carpets.

The only way I can think of that this would seriously damage a subfloor is if you have moisture issues also (e.g. several drinks spilled, very moist crawlspace directly underneath, burst or leaky pipes nearby). Frequent or prolonged exposure to moisture will cause problems in any wooden subfloor.

Creaking can be a sign that the subfloor is damaged, but it's not unusual for some fasteners (nails, mostly) to move a little in some parts of older houses. If you take up the carpet and pad and see problems with the floor (water stains or rot are obvious indications) you might need to replace part of the subfloor - but again, this would be unusual and not directly caused by the chair.

Comment: Agreed.  Casters on a bare floor WILL tear up a wood floor but when put on carpeting they will just tear up the carpeting instead.  Since you (OP) stated you can't remove the carpet, you should get a floor mat IMMEDIATELY.  They're about $45 on Amazon at present prices in the USA.

Comment: Would it still be necessary to purchase a floor mat if I am not using the office chair in the damaged spot? I am rarely seated upon it elsewhere in the home so as to not repeat any  damages. If so, what materials or characteristics should I look for in a floor mat uniquely suited to this scenario?

Comment: You should use an appropriate floor mat anywhere you have an office chair. Office chairs tear up any surface they're on, the question is do you want that to be your (semi-) permanent floor or a replaceable mat?

Comment: If you don't use a floor mat you'll just get more torn up floor.